# Reuse Channel for HTTP requests

Tags: java, netty

I want to reuse channel for multiple HTTP requests. I'm using java+netty for the server but clients could be written in C#/Java.

For the C# client I'm using `HttpWebRequest` with `KeepAlive = true;` and I don't close the channel after the arrival of the response. And it works perfect.

But when I tried the same for java <--> java communication I had some problems. I'm handling the  responses from server something like in [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java) sample and [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientHandler.java) client part.

If in `if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {` section I just do `ctx.close();` I won't be able to reuse this channel again. What should I do here to be able to reuse it?

I tried:

```
ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.CONTINUE));
```

or

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
```

or tried to do nothing...but when I try to reuse this channel, i have problem in this handle. The first request was handled fine, but the second gives me this error:

```
channelRead0: DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: failure(java.lang.NullPointerException), version: HTTP/1.1)
```

Section `if (msg instanceof HttpResponse)` works fine (I mean headers was read), but throws exception somewhere after that.

And:

```
headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
```

doesn't help too. To make it clear: 1st request/response is fine. Second request in same stream is fine, but there is a problem in decoding the response.

I checked Logger. 1st and second responses are equal, so I don't understand why it gets NullException when  decoding it.

p.s. netty 4.0.26

Comment: Could you add 1) the stack trace of the `NullPointerException` and 2) the HTTP request you've sent to the server?

Comment: @trustin there is no stacktrace, only one message from slf4j. That's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You are entirely at the mercy of the clients. If they implement connection pooling, your connection will be reused. If not, not. Nothing you can do about it at the server end except observe and implement the `Connection: close` header if sent.

Comment: Clients written by my self, where i tried to reuse connections. As i said problem is in decoding response for second request.

Comment: So, channel wasn't closed.

Comment: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientHandler.java  here they close channel after handle response, but without close (I want keep-alive) it doesn't work